# Create an expiration date field that auto expires

Tags: 8, views, nodes

We are currently migrating a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8. We have a view that shows a table of files uploaded through the file depot. One of the columns on the table was an Expiration Date. In Drupal 6 we had a module called Auto Expire to set a date for a node to expire which we used to create a field on the view showing the number of days until the link to the file expired.

We created a Node view with multiple fields as the column headings (Date Created, Expiration Date, Staff Member, File Name). For the expiration field, we used [Auto Expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_expire) to create an Expiration Date field set to 7 days after the creation date. After the 7 days, the node (file depot page) and it's attachments would get deleted.

How do I recreate this functionality (whether programmatically or otherwise) in Drupal 8, since Auto Expire is not updated for Drupal 8?

I am currently looking into the [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) module as there is a version for Drupal 8.

Comment: You can use rules to do this . An track your custom field expiration date

Comment: Really? How????

Comment: "How do I recreate Auto Expire" unfortunately is a too-broad question for Drupal Answers. Please try to get something up-and-running yourself and then ask a specific and narrow question if something's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) to unpublish the node (and then optionally use Scheduler's hooks/events to delete the node). However, to get the date set into the Scheduler unpublish_on field, you could use Rules (reacting on 'after creating' event) or use your own custom mymodule_hook_save() to set the date.

We are also in the process of migrating Scheduler's actions and events for Rules, (see https://www.drupal.org/node/2651348) and I think that Rules would then let you delete the node reacting to being unpublished by Scheduler.